# The construction of "drink them gone"

Tags: lyrics, construction, resultative

The following is from the song "no can left behind":

> How 'bout a 12-pack packed
> Just between us
> We're gonna **drink 'em all
> gone**
> Y'all this is some serious stuff

I am wondering about the construction of the phrase "drink them gone". I don't think I have seen this construction before but a similar phrase I once came across is "dream it possible" which was also used in a song.

Do the constructions of these two phrases  only occur in songs? Could you give me other examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more common phrase would be "drink them down", but "drink them all gone" is understandable, and fits with the song title "No Can Left Behind".

These examples "drink it down", "drink them all gone" and "dream it possible" fit the description of a *resultative* construction.

[Wikipedia *Resultative*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultative)

> In linguistics, a resultative (abbreviated RES) is a form that expresses that something or someone has undergone a change in state as the result of the completion of an event. Resultatives appear as predicates of sentences, and are generally composed of a verb (denoting the event), a post-verbal noun phrase (denoting the entity that has undergone a change) and a so-called resultative phrase (denoting the state achieved as the result of the action named by the verb) which may be represented by an **adjective**, a prepositional phrase, or a particle, among others. For example, in the English sentence *The man wiped the table clean*, the adjective *clean* denotes the state achieved by the table as a result of the event described as *the man wiped*.

[Emphasis added]

Comment: The verb "drink" takes object oriented Predicative Complement (PC) but they are very restricted. Semantically they licenses both depective (*drink it hot*) and resultative (*drink it dry*) PC. But I don't think "drink them all gone" are correct except in the flowery linguistic area of songs, poems etc where language don't strictly adhear to grammar. They are guided by poetic license.